# PrimeFaces Mobile requests undefined/undefined.css and undefined/undefined.js, causing JSF1064 warning and 404 error

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces-mobile

When I add a `<p:selectBooleanButton>` to my PrimeFaces Mobile page, then I get the following warning in server log

```
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, undefined/undefined.css, from library, primefaces.
Jan 11, 2015 3:00:36 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
```

and the following error in browser console:

> 404 (Not Found) `http://localhost:8080/ewpmob/javax.faces.resource/undefined/undefined.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1.7`

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in PrimeFaces mobile. This was discovered and fleshed out in the following related answer: [Why is my p:progressBar not displayed, only the number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645923/why-is-my-pprogressbar-not-displayed-only-the-number/27667540#27667540)

The workaround is, execute this script in end of head or begin of body, either inline or via a custom script file:

```
var originalPrimeFacesCw = PrimeFaces.cw;
PrimeFaces.cw = function(name, id, options, resource) {
    resource = resource || name.toLowerCase();
    originalPrimeFacesCw.apply(this, [name, id, options, resource]);
};
```